# php Date Comaprisons for date format ('j F Y')

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, advanced-custom-fields

I have two dates:

```
$today = date('j F Y');
$display_until = date('j F Y');
```

($display_until technically comes from an ACF field date selector):

[image]

I'm currently using:

```
<?php if($today < $display_until) : ?>
    *where the magic should happen*
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it's not demarcating the events as expected ... can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should convert them to epoch timestamps, then it is just two integers.

Comment: Or, that would be my idea on it

Comment: Please post the code in which `$today` and `$display_until` variables are processed. Please explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Stender - Would I just use something like `$dt_today = new DateTime($today);`

Comment: You may want to take a look at second argument for the date function in official [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) .

Comment: @rmalviya Hmmm - I'm wanting to convert a date string to a date tho, I'm not creating a date.

Comment: You can use `strtotime` function of php for that. e.g. `date('j F Y', strtotime('2017-05-01'));`. Pass your date string as a parameter to `strtotime`.

Comment: @rmalviya Worked like a charm. Happy for you to add it as an answer, even if it feels a little trivial.

Comment: I'd go with just using `DateTime` throughout personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the further explanation from your comments, you can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function of php to convert any date-like string to timestamp, and later you can pass this timestamp to `date` function to get the date back in your desired format.

Here is the code for that:

`date('j F Y', strtotime('2017-05-01'));`

if you want comparison, then:

```
if(strtotime('Jul 10, 2017') < strtotime('+10 days')) {
    // Your logic
}
```

You can also use newer [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object.

Answer (score 2):

you have two solution:

### 1

convert dates to timestamp then compare them:

```
$today = date('j F Y');
$display_until = date('j F Y');

if (strtotim($today) < strtotime($display_until)){
 //
}
```

### 2

use `DateTime` object:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$diplay_until = new DateTime(); // or new DateTime()->modify('+1 month');

if ($today < $diplay_until){
 // do something
}
```